# how to put javascript link in a value array of the cgridview?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii

e.g I want to have a link, that when i click it, it will call this  inside the CGridView array of yii framework ?

```
$('.blah').fancybox();
```

how to add that in a

```
array(
         'header'=>'Image',
         'type'=>'raw',
         'value'=> "",
              ),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [CLinkColumn's `linkHtmlOptions`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLinkColumn#linkHtmlOptions-detail) instead:

```
array(
    'class'=>'CLinkColumn',
    'linkHtmlOptions'=>array('onclick'=>'$(".blah").fancybox();'),
    'header'=>'Image',
    'label'=>'For Static Labels',// use label for static labels
    'labelExpression'=>'"Dynamic label".$row'// use labelExpression for dynamic label
)
```